# Cloning a repository from github using conda

Tags: github, anaconda, yolov5, cloning

Today I wanted to clone a repo from github but since I've never used anaconda, can anyone help me write a code in Anaconda Prompt to do this for me... The github repository link is here:`https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5`

I would highly appreciate if some one help me. Furthermore i tried cloning the repo but when i wrote the repo's link in GitHub i was faced an error saying there is no such repo

Answer (score 1):

The anaconda prompt is only a normal command prompt that has your base conda env activated and set up the `conda` command. Therefore, you jsut write

```
git clone https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5.git
```

as you would in your normal cmd

Comment: Thanks for your help ...and if it said "'git' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.", --> what should i do ?

Comment: Have you isntalled `git` in any way? If not, `conda install git` should work